# How to use homebrew-bundle to manage old terraform version

Tags: homebrew, terraform

I haven't been able to find a way to install an older version of terraform (0.11.7, specifically) using homebrew-bundle via the Brewfile. Using the homebrew cli I can just do

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0a5f283f5fa18b4bd2dc0e111ca83257af962c9d/Formula/terraform.rb
```

and I'll be set with terraform 0.11.7. But I haven't been able to figure out how to achieve that via a Brewfile. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @John - this doesn't answer your actual question, but check out `tfenv` (https://github.com/Zordrak/tfenv/). You can install and run multiple versions of Terraform on the same system and pin versions to projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but possible solution to just use binary file of proper version.
You can [download](https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/) any version of terraform and just run something like this

> terraform117 plan

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote an article that explains how you can install multiple versions of Terraform using Homebrew and switch among them on the [Gruntwork Blog](https://blog.gruntwork.io/installing-multiple-versions-of-terraform-with-homebrew-899f6d124ff9).